# Selenium Webdriver or Sahi which is best for website/mobile site testing?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, webdriver

Can anyone tell me which is the best tool to use for web site testing? Sahi or Selenium Web driver. Am using windows OS in PC. At present Testing of both Desktop and Mobile Site in Manual. Trying to jump automation. Pls assist in this regard.

Comment: This is going to be way too tough to answer. Your best bet is to give both a trial and see what works best for *your* team and come back with implementation questions. :)

Answer (score 2):

I have very positive experience with **Selenium** (desktop) and **Appium** (mobile) in collaboration.

- [**Selenium (WebDriver)**](http://docs.seleniumhq.org) has good support and a huge community of users
  *it's very easy to find solution for almost every problem*
- [**Appium**](http://appium.io) is actively developed, uses Selenium's API, supports iOS and Android, and many languages (Java, C#, Ruby, Python, PHP, etc.)
- They are good in collaboration because:

  — Multi-platform tests = the same test could be executed on desktop, iOS, Android
  — Test scaling = easy to run tests in parallel; it's based on the same technology — Selenium Grid
  — Most modern browsers are supported (almost everything for desktop, native + Chrome for mobile)

P.S. Unfortunately I have no experience with Sahi.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend Selenium. I have seen it working for major portals test automation. In terms of comparison between selenium / sahi. This link is a good answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606550/watir-vs-selenium-vs-sahi

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your requirement.

If you have good knowledge about programming language and if you have enough time for automation, then can proceed with Selenium.

If you don't have a very good knowledge of programming language and you don't have enough time to automate then can go with Sahi.

Answer (score -1):

Another alternative for teams adopting CI/CD is catjs  ( open & free ).

Catjs  represent a new approach for automation and works ( without additional configuration/code/app) on both desktop and mobile .

In addition, no need for sync point and additional maintenance even if the UI is  in its early stages .

We enable developers to automate their code in UI level and gain true agility

Have a look at http://catjsteam.github.io
Will be happy to assist if needed.

disclaimer I'm also the product owner of catjs

Comment: Hi- You should add a disclaimer that it is your product otherwise you'll be marked for spam.

Comment: log file is correct - each self-promoting post requires a disclaimer. I do believe this was an honest attempt to answer a question, so I won't delete it, but if you could add it to this and future posts (even though it's in your name). Thanks!